# Capture who has accessed the airflow webserver

Tags: airflow

I need to create an access log that can show who has accessed the airflow webserver. For example, when someone logs into an airflow webserver, then the username "User01" and the login time will be captured. Does any prodigy in stackoverflow have solved similar problem before? Thank you.

I can only find how to capture who has triggered the dag but not much information that capturing who has accessed the airflow webserver

Answer (score 1):

You can activate the webserver access log by setting the config [access_logfile](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#access-logfile) to redirect the webserver log to a file.
You can change other configs in the [webserver](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#webserver) section to limit the events.

Comment: Currently I am working in a company that the "access_logfile" in environment of airflow will not output the username as it is using token. The column of username is "-". Are there any other method to perform it? 

I am trying to check the Last login time of each user and force them to login every 30 minutes. What do you think?

Comment: you can just change this [conf](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#session-lifetime-minutes) and set it to 30, the webserver session lifetime will be 30 minutes